# Incremental search in IdeaVim

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

With `incsearch` enabled in Vim, the cursor moves to the next match as I type the first character. IdeaVim doesn't seem to respect this setting. How should I turn on incremental search in IDEA?

Comment: Good news! This is now fixed, as of ideavim 0.45. Just `set incsearch` in your .ideavimrc and you'll be up and running.

Answer (score 14):

Just put `set incsearch` into your ~/.ideavimrc

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion actually doesn't work (it in fact has a lot of side effects).  The best solution I have found so far is to simply use the built-in key combinations (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way: IDEA's normal search is incremental,  so you could use that one via <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> or its equivalent.  You could even bind <kbd>/</kbd> to invoke IDEA's find command instead of the VIM version if you want:

```
nmap / :action Find<CR>
nmap n :action FindNext<CR>
```

in your `~/.ideavimrc` or invoked at the `:` prompt.  There may be side effects to doing it this way; I haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: to clarify: It does open the "find" box, but it doesn't activate it, so you can't type anything

Answer (score 0):

According to [IdeaVim 0.46 Notes](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/update/index?pr=clion&updateId=26968), there is support for incsearch option for showing search results while typing.

Comment: Please, enhance your answer by adding more info

Comment: Rather than use a link, please extract the important information and add it to your answer, along with the referencing link to the source. That way, if the source page disappears the important information is still available. Links rot then break, and when this one does your answer won't help much.